# Difference between current and previous timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data that is updated every 5 minutes.

```
| TimeStamp | Data |
|   1       |    2 |
|   2       |    8 |
|   3       |   16 |
```

How can I select this data in such a way that it does not show the data, but the difference between the last timestamp, like this:

```
| TimeStamp | Data |
|   1       |    2 |
|   2       |    6 |
|   3       |    8 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scenario envisaged by Gordon materializes, then you can do something like this...

```
SELECT x.timestamp
     , x.data-COALESCE(MAX(y.data),0) data 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.timestamp < x.timestamp 
 GROUP 
    BY x.timestamp;
```

Comment: There is seems to be a problem when there are gaps. If I'm getting 0 data for a while, I end up with negative data and off numbers. Any suggestion about how to fix that?

Comment: I suggest you post up an sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamps have no gaps (as in the example in the question):

```
select t.timestampe,
       t.data - coalesce(tprev.data, 0) as data
from table t left outer join
     table tprev
     on t.timestamp = tprev.timestemp + 1;
```

If you have gaps, this may not work the way you want.