# MySQL Table With UNIX Timestamps - Sorting By Timestamp And Calculating Difference Between One Row And Previous

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select, sql-update

## Similar Questions

First off, I'm pretty sure something similar must be answered somewhere but I haven't been able to find it. Here are some similar pages that aren't what I'm looking for:

[MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)
That's calculating the time difference between two rows which the ID already known of both rows and in my case I have no idea what the ID will be of the previous row. Also, using DATETIME when my table is a simple Unix timestamp.

[Calculate the time difference between two timestamps in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863144/calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-mysql)
Seems to depend on functions related to a specific TIMESTAMP type.

[Difference between current and previous timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632453/difference-between-current-and-previous-timestamp)
Seems to be asking the right thing but his table doesn't have realistic timestamps and I can't get any of the answers to work.

[MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)
This one is unrelated. My time is already in timestamps so I can just subtract.

[Calculate delta(difference of current and previous row) mysql group by specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991196/calculate-deltadifference-of-current-and-previous-row-mysql-group-by-specific)
This one is pretty close, but it's a SELECT query and I'm trying to UPDATE the table to have this information in a new column so I can use it in subsequent queries. The DATEDIFF it uses could probably easily be converted to simple subtraction. I don't really want to have to set up a new table with all the possible difference values in seconds.

## What I'm Trying To Do

In Excel, I could take rows, sort them by a 'timestamp' column, and then set a new column (call it 'delta') which is equal to one timestamp minus the previous timestamp. So I'll get a value in seconds which is the time that's passed between one timestamp and the previous one. If a row was, for example, 1 second after the previous, the value would be '1' or if it was a minute later it would be '60'. All of the timestamps are Unix timestamps, so it's just seconds since January 1st 1970.

It's easy to add the new column in MySQL, but I can't seem to find the right query to populate it.

Here's an example table with the delta column filled in:

| id | timestamp | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1623400800 | NULL |
| 2 | 1623444000 | 43200 |
| 56 | 1623444060 | 60 |

## Solution Constraints

Ideally, since there are a lot of rows, I'd like something that functions similarly to what I'd do in Excel, for efficiency. That is, sorting the table and filling in the delta based on the data of the sorted table.

Granted, if that's not possible, then a query that has to do an individual search to populate 'delta' for every row is probably acceptable for the time being. I'll just have to run it a lot of times on portions of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You would just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (timestamp - lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) as delta
from t;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can do this rather painfully using variables:

```
select t.*,
       (timestamp -
        (case when (@tempt := @prevt) = null    -- never happens
              then 0
              when (@prev := timestamp) = null  -- never happens
              then 0
              else @tempt
         end)
        ) as delta
from (select t.* from t order by timestamp) t cross join
     (select @prevt := -1) params;
```

Note that this uses a `case` expression to implement "sequential" logic for the variable processing.  This is a hack and you can understand why MySQL has switched to using **standard** window functions for this type of operation.

You can try having an index on `(timestamp)` to improve performance.

EDIT:

If you have an index on `timestamp` and the timestamps are unique, then you can do:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               (timestamp - lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) as delta
        from t
       ) tt
       using (timestamp)
    set t.delta = tt.delta;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! That looks really useful and I'll play around with that further. Any idea how I can turn that SELECT query into an UPDATE query that will fill in the delta column I added? (I'd like to do many more things with the delta once I have it.)

Comment: join the query with the original table and set delta = t1 delta

Comment: Thanks nbk. I've used join a few times but to see the query you have in mind would certainly be super helpful. I'll play around and read a bit more to see if I can figure it out as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for the query. At the moment, I'm getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (ORDER BY `timestamp`)) AS `delta`". I think the brackets might be slightly wrong, but not sure. I managed to get to "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS `delta` FROM" by moving the brackets around but couldn't get past that. I'll keep playing with it. Thanks again!

Comment: My version does not support the LAG function, as this was only added in version 8 of MySQL. (The shared hosting environment I use is still on MySQL 5.) There is a link here with some work-arounds I am looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql